# overflow hidden hiding all content

Tags: css

I have [this pen](https://codepen.io/sansSpoon/pen/prBoLr), which is a snippet of a larger project, where I'm trying to hide a div as it gets transformed off to the left. The elements that needs to hide it's overflowed content is `.fixed-strip` and the element to be hidden is `.strip`. As soon as I add `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow-x: hidden;` to `.fixed-strip` it hides all the content, not just the transformed content.

```
.fixed-strip{
    max-width: 20rem;
    padding-left:  1.5rem;
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
    margin-left:  auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.strip {
    display: block;
     background-color: fade_out(rgba(122, 116, 97, 1),0.6);
    left: 0;
    top: 1rem;
    width:300px;
    height:80px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

The whole header has to be in a `position:fixed;` container for other reasons. Could this be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your pen, and if I understood what your problem is, try giving a suitable height to fixed-strip.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `height: 100%;` to `.fixed-strip`:

```
.fixed-strip {
    max-width: 20rem;
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
```

It is because `.fixed-strip` do not have a height at all and it just displaying the overflow by default. It did not fill the height because the child was `position: absolute;` that's why once you `overflow: hidden` everything is hidden as it doesn't have a height for the items to be displayed.

Hope that help.

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation, up voting your answer, but award to @deg, 'cause he got in 1minute earlier ;)